# How do I get The Last Word?

Tags: destiny

In Year 1, I do remember having The Last Word for a short time. I don't remember how I got it, but I remember taking one look and deciding the weapon wasn't really for me. (Some may call this a handicap, but "shooting from the hip" doesn't really fit my playstyle and TLW *heavily* favors players who do.) So, I dismantled it since I never planned to use it and Vaults weren't really that spacious back then.

Now we're in Year 2 and The Taken King is here. Along with it, a quest called "Jolly Holliday" which *requires* TLW in order to be completed. I'm really hoping Bungie didn't give this to us without also giving us a relatively easy way of getting TLW. Considering that many Year 1 players - even some of the most devoted Day 1 veterans - wouldn't have gotten Gjallarhorn without Xur's help, it seems absurd to make any quest rely on a player having a specific Exotic.

So, I know this is a stretch but, I'm really hoping someone can help me out here. Is there any method - short of waiting for Xur to stock it - that gives a substantially higher-than-random (if not guaranteed) chance of spawning TLW? Or am I just stuck with this quest in my queue until I get that lucky?

Comment: Shoot the other person after you finish your sentence.

Comment: Xur was finally selling Legacy Primary Exotics this past weekend. And I got lucky - first one I bought was The Last Word. And now, I was faced with the reality of the "Shindig in the Crucible" quest. Ugh. Maybe next week they'll bring Mayhem back and I'll have better luck there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only guaranteed method of receiving a specific exotic is to craft it using exotic blueprints. In this case, you'd need the year 1 version of The Last Word to craft the year 2 version.

Don't despair, as you do still have some options:

- Exotic year 2 primary engrams as well as legendary primary engrams can decrypt to The Last Word. You can acquire a lot of exotic year 2 engrams (but with no control over the slot) by using Xur's new Three Of Coins items. Three of Coins are best used with several minutes between them. The item itself will grant you a chance to receive an exotic engram on your next Ultra kill (enemy with a skull health bar) or completion of your next crucible match. The chance to receive an exotic engram will increase every time the Three of Coins buff is consumed without getting an exotic engram.
- Nightfall Strikes can reward The Last Word (I've already received one).
- Xur can sell The Last Word.
- Xur has begun selling "Legacy" engrams - these will decrypt into a year 1 exotic for that slot. They have a very high preference to exotics **not currently in your collection**. These typically cost 36 coins.
- Oryx's chest has a chance of rewarding exotics.
- Trials of Osiris packages have a chance to reward exotics.

Comment: These are all well and good, but essentially this is just a guide on "how to get exotics in general". The only "higher than random" chance they offer me of specifically dropping TLW is from the fact that Bungie has tweaked the RNG to favor exotics we don't already have - and I happen to not have TLW. Also, I tried a full stack of Three of Coins recently. Didn't do squat for me. :-(

Comment: @Iszi - They recently nerfed the three of coins. The best process I have found for using them is to use 8 all at once after getting the strike bonus. This has yielded an exotic drop for me 5 times so far. However, out of all the coin drops and from other players I have talked to, the three of coins engram has always been armor. From 17 drops I have heard of, they have all been armor.

Comment: @Iszi Unfortunately, this is the only advice you can get for getting The Last Word. There isn't a quest to get it, the only way to get it is as a random drop or from Xûr.

Comment: @TravisJ They only nerfed Three of Coins used in rapid succession (i.e. the farming trick). They're of the same effectiveness if you use them normally - one per strike has netted me and most people on reddit exotics at roughly the same rate as before (one engram per 5-6 coins). They can still include weapon engrams, as I just received a Telesta from one last night.

Comment: @Iszi The best way to use Three of Coins is to buy them in bulk (say, around 50-60), use one at a time, and go run a bunch of level 36 strikes. Other than that, you don't have a guaranteed method unless Xur sells the year 2 version (23 coins) or bulk-purchasing the legacy engrams (36 coins each - not a great deal) and then crafting the year 2 version (125 marks).

Comment: @twobugs - Well at least you getting an exotic weapon gives me hope. Which ultra dropped it, if you don't mind me asking? The rapid succession was what made them so useful in my opinion, so that is why I believe it was a nerf. I think I still have like 50 left over that I am now using one at a time in the current environment.

Comment: I believe my Telesta came from Bond Brothers, but I did upwards of 20+ strikes yesterday so I don't remember for sure :P Note that if you don't return to orbit, this is also a decent way to earn reputation with the vanguard, the cryptarchs, and your chosen faction.

Comment: @TravisJ why would you use 8 at a time? They don't stack.  You can definitely get exotic weapon engrams as well, I have.

Comment: @turbo - Says right in the tooltip that they stack.

Comment: @twobugs - Confirmed, I got an exotic weapon engram last night, but it was Invective of all things :(

Comment: @TravisJ you're misinterpreting: "Xûr will also sell a new consumable, the Three of Coins, which gives bosses a chance to drop Exotic Engrams, including Weapon Engrams. These consumables have a cumulative luck effect, so even if one doesn’t net you a drop, the next one has a higher chance to do so." [Source: BWU 9/17/2015](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/News?aid=13575).  The "stackable" effect is the increased drop chance. Using multiple does not increase your chances more until the three of coins has been consumed.

Comment: @turbo - The tooltip states "Stackable effect that increases the chances the next Ultra you defeat will drop an Exotic Engram." I took stackable to mean that you can use multiple at once and the effect will stack. I see the quote you are showing, but have also had success using many at once. I am not sure that using more than one at one time has no effect.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree the tooltip is a bit ambiguous. However, people report a ratio of about 5 coins to 1 exotic using the one-at-a-time method.  You can read around for other's accounts.  How has your luck been using 8 at a time?

Comment: @turbo - What I would do was use one on a heroic strike. And then on the second strike once I had the buff I would use all 8. This worked 4 times in a row to yield an exotic engram, but they were all armor :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29683/discussion-between-turbo-and-travis-j).

Answer (score 1):

Buy the year one exotic weapon engrams in bulk and cross your fingers. In fact, every process will include luck. There is no way to increase your odds of getting TLW.

Even if the RNG was adjusted (I found no reference to that anywhere, citation required) there is no way of increasing the adjusted odds. Any exotic roll which would include TLW would have those odds (adjusted or not) aside from doing the new content raids.

Xur is basically your best bet. You are stuck with the quest line until then.

That said, are you entirely positive this weapon is not available on the "wall of weapons" in the vanguard section of the tower? If you obtained a weapon at any point it should exist in that wall. This would mean you can obtain the year one weapon for a single exotic shard, or the new 280 version for 150 legendary marks.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the exotic weapon armor/blueprints for year 1 equipment just uses what was on your characters or vault when the 2.0 patch hit - Bungie themselves admitted they didn't have satisfactory methods for tracking previous exotic acquisition.

Comment: It is hard for me to verify that, I could not find any sources indicating the availability algorithm, and I kept all of my exotics so it wasn't possible to see for myself.

Comment: @twobugs You are correct, as I am missing some exotics that I deleted for vault space.  However, on Bungie's part, that's a BS excuse.. you get a grimoire card for every exotic weapon the first time it drops for you. All the would have to do is check which grimoire cards you have and unlock those respective weapons.

Comment: I can verify that the blueprints on day 1 of 2.0 only included the exotics you had equipped, in inventory, or in the vault when 2.0 was applied. The TLW I disassembled before 2.0 is not available.

Comment: @turbo Guess they don't trust the Grimoire tracker? I wouldn't either, considering I have some cards for "Crucible Kills as..." (or something similar) Warlock/Titan even though I nearly never go into Crucible with anything but my Hunter.

Comment: @Iszi, that's a different bug though.  I think it counts assists as kills for other classes or something like that.  I don't even have a warlock and I have like half the needed kills for that grimoire card.  There's no way (that I'm aware of) to fake the exotic grimoire cards. Maybe someday they'll fix it, not really trying to spending 30 SC on legacy engrams.

Comment: I don't think assists are even the problem, or at least not the whole of it. I've seen Grimoire cards trigger when I'm not even making kills or dealing any damage.

Comment: @Iszi - If you are aiming at something that dies, sometimes you get partial credit for it.

Comment: @TravisJ Is Bungie implying I'm ugly? That it just died because I looked at it?

Comment: @Iszi - Well that isn't for me to say :P The easiest way to confirm this is in the crucible. If you aim at someone without shooting that a teammate kills, you get an assist.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I found that still works is farming the Prison of Elders, which would require the treasure keys, so hopefully you still have some. If not, complete the House of Wolves story line on all your characters and take that treasure key- one per character, and only use one per character for the crystal barrows. Or, you can do the nightfall/3 of coins/legendary primary engram/exotic primary.

Comment: Hm. Wonder how easy PoE is at Light 300+ now? Doubt it's soloable due to mechanics, but still. Also, one Wolves bounty per week (probably per character, too - so up to three) should drop a key.

Comment: @Iszi PoE is still not soloable. I attempted lv32 at 293 light, and I got roflstomped

Comment: @Wondercricket I'd expect it to be fairly soloable (albeit probably a bit tricky) up to Skolas. But Skolas' mechanics make soloing difficult at the start and practically (if not completely) impossible halfway in.

Comment: @Iszi, You can solo 35 PoE.  You can block the poison during the Skolas round with a sword block.  With 3 people, you can also burn him with ToM (and small arms I think) before he even spawns the mines.

Comment: @turbo Didn't even think about the sword block. Man, that thing is borderline OP.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best method to farm exotic year two engrams is to farm the Ultra Knight on the Dreadnaught. To find him, load into into the map, go to the place where the door is before you fight the tank and kill all the adds there. Also don't forget your Three of Coins.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is pop a three of coins pick a mission. Then kill the boss and yourself at the same time with a rocket at close range. There is a ok chance he will drop a exotic engram just remember to pick it up. In under five minutes I got 3 exotic engrams. It works really well I would recommend the scourge of winter quest with Draxis.

Comment: I do not recommend doing this as this method was nerfed about a week after The Taken King launched. Not intended to be used in rapid succession.